# Python Subsequence of a String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

The exercise asks me to write a program. It wrote

"Given a string `s` and a string `t`, check if `s` is a subsequence of `t`.

For example: `"ac", "abcd" => True`."

So I wrote this:

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
        s, t = map(list, [s, t])
        for c in t:
            if c in s:
                s.pop(0)
        return not s
```

It worked ok in most cases except one:

```
s = "rjufvjafbxnbgriwgokdgqdqewn"
t = "mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq"
```

I don't know why my code didn't work on this one. So if someone knows the answer, please tell me.

Comment: Your code is testing whether every character in `s` is also in `t` *in any order* -- here's a simple example: `isSubsequence('ab', 'acb')` => `True`. There are easier ways of testing sequence membership in Python but since it's an exercise I'm not going to just tell you ;-)

Comment: Why `s.pop(0)`?!

Comment: @Juniktw I suggest you look at a simpler example like `isSubsequence('ab', 'bb')`. Your code currently returns `True` for that, which is obviously not the desired result...

Comment: Yes it worked for simple test cases but not working for the larger test case as above.

Comment: @Juniktw No, it **does not** work for that simple case. It should return `False`, since `'ab'` is clearly not a subsequence of `'bb'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
    s = list(s)
    for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(t,s)):
        if a != b:
            s.insert(i,'.')
    return len(t) == len(s)
    
print(isSubsequence('Apes are goo.', 'Apples are good.'))
```

Output:

```
True
```

---

---

---

Your case is that that specific `s` is *not* a subsequence of that specific `t`. To prove it:

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
    s = list(s)
    for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(t,s)):
        if a != b:
            s.insert(i,'.')
    print(t)
    print(''.join(s))

s = "rjufvjafbxnbgriwgokdgqdqewn"
t = "mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq"

isSubsequence(s, t)
```

Output:

```
mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq
......r...........................j.u...................f...............................................................v..............................j..................................................................................................a................f..b..............................................................................x............n...b....................g....................................................................................r...i.......................wgokdgqdqewn
```

---

---

---

*UPDATED to include simpler implementation given by @StevenRumbalski at the comments:*

```
def isSubsequence(s, t, start=-1): 
    return all((start:=t.find(c, start+1)) > -1 for c in s)
```

Comment: Another simple implementation (Python 3.8+) `def isSubsequence(s, t, start=0): return all((start:=t.find(c, start)) > -1 for c in s)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That is broken, since it will return `True` for `isSubsequence('bb', 'abc')`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62612001/984421) for a correct implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: @ekhumoro: fixed: `def isSubsequence(s, t, start=-1): return all((start:=t.find(c, start+1)) > -1 for c in s)`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the order also matters

```
def isSubsequence(s, t): # order matters
    s, t = list(s), list(t)
    for c in s:
        if c in t:
            c_idx = t.index(c)
            t = t[c_idx:]
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
    start = -1
    for i in s:
      start = t.find(i, start + 1)
      if start == -1:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: It's smpler to use [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) with a `start` argument. If the result is `-1`, return `False`, otherwise use `result + 1` for the next `start` argument.

Comment: @RonieMartinez That looks broken. You want `start = -1` and `start = t.find(i, start + 1)`, and also remove `start += 1`.