# How to find if given string is a subsequence of another given string recursively without imports?

Tags: python, string, recursion, subset, subsequence

Assignment:

> Write a recursive function named is_subsequence that takes two
> string parameters and returns True if the first string is a
> subsequence of the second string, but returns False otherwise. We say
> that string A is a subsequence of string B if you can derive A by
> deleting zero or more letters from B without changing the order of the
> remaining letters. You can assume that neither string contains
> upper-case letters.
>
> You may use default arguments and/or helper functions.
>
> Your recursive function must not:
> use imports.
> use any loops use any variables declared outside of the function.
> use any mutable default arguments.

What I have so far (must use this format):

```
def is_subsequence(strA, strB = None):
if strB == None:
   strB = []

print(is_subsequence("dog", "dodger"))
```

My problem:
I can't figure out how to recursively edit the string the way the assignment says by removing letters. (`strB.replace("e","")` doesn't work).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611839/python-subsequence-of-a-string

Comment: You could try that, but I'll give you a hint: that isn't the right approach for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is allowed based on the instructions but i added an index param and was able to come up with this. (Snippet is Python)

```js
def is_subsequence(strA, strB, index=0):
    """
    Function that determines if string A is a subsequence of string B
    :param strA: String to compare subsets to (strings are immutable)
    :param strB: Parent string to make subsets of (strings are immutable)
    :param index: number of combinations tested
    :return: True if a subsequence is found, False if index reaches maximum with none found
    """

    binary = '{:0{leng}b}'.format(index, leng=len(strB))

    if index > 2**len(strB)-1:  #If past maximum return False
        return False

    def makesub(sub="", pos=0):
        """
        Function that builds up the current subsequence being tested by using binary to choose letters
        :param sub: The currently selected letters
        :param pos: Position in binary string to compare
        :return: completed subsequence for comparing to strA
        """
        if pos > len(binary)-1: #If pos is passed the length of our binary number return the created subsequence
            return sub
        if binary[pos] == "1":  #If the pos in binary is a 1, add the letter to our sub. If it is 0 do nothing.
            sub = sub + strB[pos]

        return makesub(sub, pos + 1)    #increment pos and try again or return what the call returned

    if makesub() == strA:       #If the returned sub matches strA we found a matching subsequence, return True
        return True

    return is_subsequence(strA, strB, index + 1)    #increment index and try again or return what the call returned


print(is_subsequence("dog", "dodger"))
```